# WCF Websocket, unable to connect from browser

Tags: .net, wcf, websocket

For some reason I am unable to connect to my WebSocket server from my javascript client.

My server:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IHelloCallback))]
public interface IHelloService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task Hello(string msg);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    Task OnHello(string msg);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class HelloService : IHelloService
{
    public async Task Hello(string msg)
    {
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IHelloCallback>();
        await callback.OnHello(msg);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
    ["aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext"] = "true";

  var mapping = new System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ProtocolMappingElementCollection();
  mapping.Add(
    element: new ProtocolMappingElement(
      schemeType: "http",
      binding: "netHttpBinding",
      bindingConfiguration: "default"));
  mapping.Add(
    element: new ProtocolMappingElement(
      schemeType: "https",
      binding: "netHttpsBinding",
      bindingConfiguration: "default"));

  ServiceHost serviceHost = null;

  try {
    string addressStr = "http://localhost:27272/HelloService";

    var binding = new NetHttpBinding(
      securityMode: BasicHttpSecurityMode.None,
      reliableSessionEnabled: true);

    var addressUri = new Uri(uriString: addressStr);

    serviceHost = new ServiceHost(
      serviceType: typeof(HelloService),
      baseAddresses: addressUri);

    var endpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
      implementedContract: typeof(IHelloService),
      binding: binding,
      address: addressUri);

    serviceHost.Open();

    Console.WriteLine(
      "WebSocketsServiceValues service is running, press any key to close...");
    Console.ReadKey();

  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
  }
  finally {
    serviceHost.Close();
  }
}
}
```

My client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>WebSocket Chat</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ws;
        $().ready(function () {
            $("#btnConnect").click(function () {
                $("#spanStatus").text("connecting");
                ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:27272/HelloService");
                ws.onopen = function () {
                    $("#spanStatus").text("connected");
                };
                ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                    $("#spanStatus").text(evt.data);
                };
                ws.onerror = function (evt) {
                    $("#spanStatus").text(evt.message);
                };
                ws.onclose = function () {
                    $("#spanStatus").text("disconnected");
                };
            });
            $("#btnSend").click(function () {
                if (ws.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
                    ws.send($("#textInput").val());
                }
                else {
                    $("#spanStatus").text("Connection is closed");
                }
            });
            $("#btnDisconnect").click(function () {
                ws.close();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Connect" id="btnConnect" />
    <input type="button" value="Disconnect" id="btnDisconnect" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="textInput" />
    <input type="button" value="Send" id="btnSend" /><br />
    <span id="spanStatus">(display)</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could this be down to running the webpage above locally rather than through a web server?

Comment: is there an error message is shown on the browser console? In chrome try righ click -> Inspect element -> console

Comment: Please post your config file.

Comment: @jhadesdev - No console errors.

Comment: @Dunken - what config file...there is no `app.config` as the config is in the code above.

Comment: OK. You're on Windows 8, right?

Comment: @Dunken - yes Windows 8.

Comment: have you enabled websockets in iis?

Comment: @vtortola - this is not hosted within IIS, it's a console application. But to answer your question - I have not touched IIS.

Comment: I am not completely sure, but just in case, try this http://forums.asp.net/post/5084249.aspx and please comment back if it worked :)

Comment: @vtortola - tried, no change.

Answer (score 1):

I did notice something interesting.  Might help you:
The message that your client sends the server looks like this:

```
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: upgrade
Host: localhost:27272
Origin: null
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 6hblahblahblah
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13 --- THIS IS INTERESTING
etc...
```

If you use Fiddler and switch it to

```
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13, 7
```

or practically any number other than 13,

```
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 12
```

```
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 14
```

you will get a 426 response from the server, which I think is the proper next step for the negotiation.  I did some research on this and the msdn api you are using is practically non-documente and the JavaScript api is lame (you cannot seemingly configure headers there).

Comment: Yeah in Javascript they will not give you access to the headers, its something controlled by the browser. Just for reference, I am running my client in Internet Explorer 11 so would expect the two protocols to work together.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off reliable session:

```
var binding = new NetHttpBinding(
  securityMode: BasicHttpSecurityMode.None,
  reliableSessionEnabled: false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. might help : [MSDN Using the NetHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674273%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I guess this is missing in your config:

```
<bindings>
  <netHttpBinding>
    <binding name="My_NetHttpBindingConfig">
      <webSocketSettings transportUsage="WhenDuplex"/>
    </binding>
  </netHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: WebSocketSettings = WhenDuplex is a default setting in NetHttpBiniding. Also, author is not using conifg.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to enable WCF Tracing on the server, so you have a better understanding of what the WCF Service listener is doing when the client makes the call (e.g. is the service even “seeing” the request? what exceptions does the service throw (as recorded in the trace log)?

For reference:
WCF tracing provides diagnostic data for fault monitoring and analysis. You can use tracing instead of a debugger to understand how an application is behaving, or why it faults. 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In the absence of additional diagnostic information, I would suggest reviewing the server bindings.  In particular, the messageEncoding setting in the netHttp(s)Binding.  By default the `netHttpBinding` and `netHttpsBinding` bindings transfer data in `Binary` format, but based on your client code, you may want to switch the `messageEncoding` to `Text`.

Good luck